# algebra with topology homework problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, ring-theory, ideals

[image]

Hello Everyone, I have this homework problem, I'm going to share what i have so far, not sure if Im in the right path. First, I have: $$f \sim g \,  \Leftrightarrow \,x_0 \in \mathbb{R^n}, \exists \,U \ni x_0\,\mid f|_U = g|_U$$

(A) Reflexivity: $f \sim f \Rightarrow$ for $x_0 \in \mathbb{R^n}, \exists \,U \ni x_0\,\mid f|_U = f|_U$

(B)Symmetry:  If $f \sim g$ then $g \sim f$ $\Rightarrow$ for $x_0 \in \mathbb{R^n}, \exists \,U \ni x_0\,\mid f|_U = g|_U$ and $g|_U = f|_U$

(C)Transitivity:
If $f \sim g$ and $g \sim h$, then $f \sim h \Rightarrow $ for $ x_0 \in \mathbb{R^n}, \exists \,U,V \ni x_0\,\mid f|_U = g|_U$ and $\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,g|_V = h|_V,$ therefore $f|_{U \cap V} = h|_{U \cap V}$, so $f \sim h$

Now, the equivalence class are defined as follows:
 $$[f]= \{\varphi \in C_{x_0}\ | \varphi \sim f\} \Rightarrow \varphi|_U = f|_U $$

$$[g]= \{\pi \in C_{x_0}\ | \pi \sim g\}  \Rightarrow \pi|_V = g|_V$$

They are welldefined, lets suppose that $[f]=[\phi]$ and $[g]=[\psi]$, then we say that:$[f]+[g] = [\phi]+[\psi] $ and $[f][g]=[\phi][\psi] $. Now by definition,for $x_0 \in \mathbb{R^n}, \exists \,U \ni x_0\, ,f|_U = \phi|_U$ and $\exists \, V \ni x_0\ ,g|_V = \psi|_V $, this implies that:$$(f+g)|_{U \cap V} = (\phi+\psi)|_{U \cap V} \Rightarrow [f + g] = [\phi + \psi],$$ $$(f g)|_{U \cap V} = (\phi \psi)|_{U \cap V} \Rightarrow [f  g] = [\phi  \psi]$$

So they are well defined.On the other hand, I have: $$\phi:C_{x_0} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}, \phi[f]=f(x_0) $$

So the kernel of $\phi$ is $M_{x_0}$, so by the first isomorphism theorem, we have that:
$$ C_{x_0}/M_{x_0} \cong \mathbb{R} $$Now, $\mathbb{R}$ is a field, therefore $C_{x_0}/M_{x_0} $ is a field $\Rightarrow$ $M_{x_0}$ is maximal. To prove that $M_{x_0}$ is the unique maximal, first we notice that $M_{x_0}$ contains no units, so if $f \notin M_{x_0}.$ Then $f(x_0) \neq 0 \Rightarrow \exists \, U \ni x_0$ such that $f(y) \neq 0, \forall y \in U \Rightarrow 1/f$ exists in a neighborhood of $x_0, \, \Rightarrow 1/f$ is a unit in $C_{x_0} \Rightarrow C_{x_0}$ is a $\mathbf{local \,ring}$, so $M_{x_0}$ is the unique maximal by the characterization of $\mathbf{local\, rings}$

Now to prove that $M_{x_0}$ is finitely generated, We have:
$$ h(1) - h(0) = \int^1_0 h'(s)\,ds$$ where $f(x_0)=0 $ in $M_{x_0}$ and $h(s) = f(s(x-x_0) +x_0)$. On the other hand, $$h'(s) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial s}, $$ 
but $\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial s} = (x_i - x_0^{i}),$ this is true because for $s \in \mathbb{R}$ and notice that $h:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, therefore $(s(x-x_0) +x_0) \in \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow (s(x_i-x_0^{i}) +x_0) \in \mathbb{R^n} $. Now, $h(1) = f(x)$ and $ h(0) = f(x_0)=0$. Hence: $$f(x) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n (x_i-x_0^{i})\cdot(\int^1_0 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\,ds),$$ Now, since the integral $\int^1_0 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\,ds$ depends on the variable $s$, we thus have that the generators of $M_{x_0}$ are $(x_i-x_0^{i})$. In other words,
$$M_{x_0} = \langle x_1-x_0^{1},x_2-x_0^{2}, \cdots, x_n-x_0^{n}\rangle$$

Now im not sure about a few thing:

1) this is the right proof for the equivalence relation ${\bf Done}$

2) I don't understand how to proof that they are well defined ${\bf Done}$

3) $C_{x_0}/M_{x_0} $ is a field, then $M_{x_0} $ is maximal, this prove that is the unique one. ${\bf Done}$

4) Is the procedure in $M_{x_0}$ is finitely generated clear or I need some other stuff, my professor told me that the functions in the exercise are smooth too

Comment: for transitivity there may be one neighborhood that works for $f,g$ and another that works for $g,h$, and you should take the intersection of these two neighborhoods, which will work for $f,h$. It is not meant in the definition of the equivalence that the same neighborhood $U$ should work for all $f,g$.

Comment: for transitivity would be something like this:

If $f \sim g$ and $g \sim h$, then $f \sim h \Rightarrow $ for $ x_0 \in \mathbb{R^n}, \exists \,U,V \ni x_0\,\mid f|_U = g|_U$ and $\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,g|_V = h|_V,$ therefore $f|_{U \cap V} = h|_{U \cap V}$, so $f \sim h$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2. Suppose $[f] = [\phi], [g] = [\psi].$ Then we need to say that $[f] + [g] = [\phi] + [\psi].$ By definiton, $\exists \,U \ni x_0\,, f|_U = \phi|_U$ and $\exists \,V \ni x_0\,, g|_V = \psi|_V.$ So $(f + g)|_{U \cap V} = (\phi + \psi)|_{U \cap V} \Rightarrow [f + g] = [\phi + \psi].$ This proves that the addition is well defined. Similarly, you can prove that the multiplication is well defined.
3. ${\bf Fact:}$ Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unity. Suppose that the set of all non-units of $A$ forms an ideal $\mathfrak{m}.$ Then $A$ has a unique maximal ideal, and $\mathfrak{m}$ is the maximal ideal.

In this case, all the elements of $M_{x_0}$ are non-unit. Let $f \notin M_{x_0}.$ Then $f(x_0) \neq 0 \Rightarrow \exists $ open nbd $U$ of $x_0$ such that $f(y) \neq 0, \forall y \in U \Rightarrow 1/f$ exists in a nbd of $x_0$ and clearly it is a unit in $C_{x_0}.$ Thus by the above fact $M_{x_0}$ is the unique maximal ideal of $C_{x_0}.$

Comment: @Krishfor multiplication $U \cap V$ would work too, right? and for 3) it suffices to say that $M_{x_0}$ has no units $\Rightarrow$ $M_{x_0}$ is the unique maximal, thank you for that fact.

Comment: by definition of prime/maximal ideal, it doesn't contain any units. but that doesn't mean that the prime/maximal ideal is unique. for example, let $A = \mathbb{Z}.$ then every ideal generated by prime elements are maximal and non of it contains any unit. rings with unique maximal ideals are called ${\bf local}$ ${\bf rings}$. see any algebra book (e.g. Dummit & Foote) for their characterization. and yes, for multiplication $U \cap V$ also works.

Comment: thank you, now I have the idea clear about the characterization of local rings and unique maximals

Comment: @krish...I added the prove of why $M_{x_0}$ is finitely generated.

Comment: @Ricardo Cervantes: how $h$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$? It looks to me that $h$ is function from $[0, 1]$ to $C_{x_0},$ where each $s \in [0, 1]$ defines a function $f(x) \mapsto f(s(x - x_0) + x_0).$ May be I'm missing something here, but it's not clear to me.